# Regex for escaping quotes in a string

Tags: regex, sed

I have a string in the file

```
"abc def ghi " klm "ghi ";
```

I want to escape all occurrences of " in the string , output of the result

```
"abc def ghi \" klm \"ghi";
```

Answer (score 1):

Since sed do not look ahead, I think we need to do it twice. Here is the code:

```
echo '"abc def ghi " klm "ghi ";' | sed -r 's/(\")/\\"/g'    | sed -r 's/(^\"|\";$)/";/g'
# ^ Print the text                  ^ Replace all " with \"    ^ Replace the first and the last \" back to "
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

awk

```
$ awk '{gsub("\"","\\\"")}1' file
abc def ghi \" klm \"ghi
```

or

```
$ awk -vq="\042" '{gsub(q,"\\"q)}1' file
abc def ghi \" klm \"ghi
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it in sed

```
> echo "abc def ghi \" klm \" ghi"
abc def ghi " klm " ghi
> echo "abc def ghi \"klm \" ghi" | sed 's/"/\\"/g'
abc def ghi \" klm \" ghi
```

Comment: In this case, however, the shell has taken care of the first and last quotes for you.  This would not be the case if the input was taken from a file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pipe `sed` into `sed`, you can do it all in one step:

```
echo '"abc def ghi " klm "ghi ";' | sed 's/\"/\\"/g; s/^\\"\(.*\)\\"/\"\1\"/'
```

Some versions of `sed` prefer it this way:

```
echo '"abc def ghi " klm "ghi ";' | sed -e 's/\"/\\"/g' -e 's/^\\"\(.*\)\\"/\"\1\"/'
```

I used a capture group, but you could use alternation instead.